# setState provokes Minified React error #130 only on production build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, netlify

Every time I interact with the drop-down button on the front page of my application, the error https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args is logged in the console. This is only when I push it to my production server, it works fine in the developer environment.

I have debugged every piece of the stack trace, and have tracked it down to the setState method from the `collapse` function in the `Quicklinks` class. This is called in the `QLButton` class, which is a child of `Quicklinks`.

```
export default class Quicklinks
    extends React.Component<Props> {
    props: Props;
    state: State;
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.collapse = this.collapse.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            collapsed: true
        }
    }

    // Collapse function intended to be called in a child
    // Invoking this crashes the page
    collapse = () => this.setState({ collapsed: !this.state.collapsed });
    


    private QuickLinkExpanded = () =>
        <>
            <ul className="ql-expanded-container ql-links ql-tree-stem">
                <button className="ql-expanded-title clickable"
                    onClick={this.collapse}>{this.props.title}</button>
                {this.props.children}
            </ul>
        </>

    public static Item = (props: { link: string, name: string }) =>
        <>
            <li className="ql-item ql-tree-branch"><a href={props.link}>{props.name}</a></li>
        </>

    render = () =>
        <>
            <div className="ql-container">

                <When condition={this.state.collapsed}>
                    <QLButton title={this.props.title} action={this.collapse} />
                </When>

                <When condition={!this.state.collapsed}>
                    <this.QuickLinkExpanded />
                </When>

            </div>
        </>
}
```

```
export default class QLButton
    extends React.Component<Props> {

    state: State;
    animationRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.animationRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            title: props.title,
            animating: false
        }
    }

    render(): React.ReactElement {
        return <>
            <button onClick={this.onClick} className="ql-btn clickable">

                <When condition={this.state.animating}>
                    <div className="ql-typing-text">
                        {"exec tree ./"}
                        <span className="ql-cursor" ref={this.animationRef} />
                    </div>
                </When>

                <div className="ql-title-text">
                    {this.state.title}
                </div>

                <When condition={!this.state.animating}>
                    <div className="ql-btn-icon">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} />
                    </div>
                </When>

            </button>
        </>
    }

    private onClick = (): void => {
        if (this.state.animating) return;
        this.setState({ animating: !this.state.animating }, this.openQuicklinks);
    }

    private openQuicklinks = (): void => {
        anime.timeline()
            .add({
                targets: this.animationRef.current,
                translateX: [...Array(9)].map((_, i) => ({
                    value: ((i + 1) * 0.57) + "em",
                    duration: 100,
                })),
                easing: "easeInOutBack",
            })
            .add({
                targets: this.animationRef.current,
                duration: 700,
                opacity: [
                    { value: [1, 1] },
                    { value: [0, 0] },
                    { value: [1, 1] },
                    { value: [0, 0] }
                ],
            }).finished.then(() => {
                this.props.action(); // This call goes to the Quicklinks parent
            })
    }
}
```

Reading related articles, I have tested for imports being done incorrectly (they all seem fine), I have removed the package_lock.json and refreshed it, and messed with the lines and surrounding code where the trace points too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suggested to me to move `QuicklinkExpanded` and `Item` outside of the `Quicklinks` class. This actually fixed the crashing in production. I am not sure why, this is likely a bug with react and ts compiling to js.